# Filter tuple facts to new list

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm having an issue with trying to filter facts imported through a CSV. I have the following CSV file:

```
"colA","colB","colC","colD"
"what","is","the","chocolate"
"hello","my","friend","person"
"time","for","some","food"
"when","is","my","event"
```

This is imported in my file using `csv_read_file` function. As an example I'm able to then run `check` to see if there is a fact with a third word imported in the CSV that contains the letter 'e' with `check('e')`.

```
:- use_module(library(csv)).

import :-
    csv_read_file('./data.csv', Data, [functor(fact)]),
    maplist(assert, Data).

check(Q) :-
        fact(_,_,S,_),
        sub_string(S,_,_,_,Q).
```

What i'm trying to do now is reduce the subset of facts imported through the CSV that contain 'e', and store those in another data type to use later on. This isn't working but what I'm trying to do is filter all facts like in `check('e')` but store the results in `Output`.

```
filter(Q, Output) :-
        findall(
                fact(_,_,S,_),
                sub_string(S,_,_,_,Q),
                Output
        ).
```

I can print all out, is it possible to store this in a list?

```
forall((fact(A,B,S,D), sub_string(S,_,_,_,'e')), print(S)).
```

Also tried with this

```
include(sub_string(S,_,_,_,'e'), fact(A,B,S,D), R).
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right using `findall/3` to collect your output onto a list. Check out the [documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) for findall though.

If you want to collect all matching S from fact/4 you may use:

```
filter(Q, Output) :-
    findall(S,
            ( fact(_, _, S, _),
              sub_string(S, _, _, _, Q)
            ),
            Output).
```

and if you want to gather the whole fact it would be something like this:

```
filter(Q, Output) :-
    findall(fact(A, B, S, C),
            ( fact(A, B, S, C),
              sub_string(S, _, _, _, Q)
            ),
            Output).
```

Note that `sub_string/5` backtracks so it may match the substring more than once for each string.